# JMeter - How can I build a test that starts a specific number of concurrent threads and repeats that test for an hour

Tags: jmeter

Hi I need to build a test in JMeter that starts 2 concurrent threads  and I also need to repeat that test for a period of an hour

**Number of Threads** : 2

**Ramp-up Period** : 0 (To have concurrent threads)

Now the question is , what if I want to repeat this for an hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all provide enough loops or even make your test to run forever.
2. Click `Scheduler` box in your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and type "3600" into "Duration" input.
    [image: JMeter Thread Group Runtime Settings]
3. Put your test logic under [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) with the same "3600" runtime value.

   [image: Runtime Controller]
4. There is an [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) available through JMeter Plugins which provides convenient way of defining load scenario.

Using zero in Ramp-up doesn't guarantee 2 (or whatever) concurrent users, to assure that the load will be no less than 2 I would recommend using [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer).

Comment: Sorry to bother you, do you think you could show me some screenshots of what you suggested? I'm really new to JMeter and most of the terms you mentioned sound unfamiliar to me :S

Comment: Added a screenshot for point 3. Thread group settings: Number of threads: 2, Ramp-up: 0, Loop Count: forever.