# How to load a single SOAP Request with multiple authentication in Jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am very new to Jmeter and need to perform a load testing of one SOAP request with 100 Authentication data. I tried the below approach, where I saved the authentication data in CSV file, using CSV Data Config parameterised and passed onto HTTP Authorisation Manager. I am able to sequentially test the SOAP request with all the user authentication data available in CSV, but I need to run concurrently, with all the 100 users. Thanks in advance.

[I have 5 users authentication(username/password) in csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsvRr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set your `Number of Threads` to 100, and the `Loop Count` to 1.

`Number of Threads` has to do with the number of concurrent users that get run.

`Loop Count` has to do with how many times a user actually does your script.

Note that if your ramp-up is slower than your script time, some users will finish before your test reaches its full concurrency. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872851/jmeter-how-can-i-build-a-test-that-starts-a-specific-number-of-concurrent-thre/25873335#25873335) for use with the scheduler.

Comment: Thank you @RowlandB .. Had to add a synchronizing timer in addition to your answer.. Anyway thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make all the requests to fire at the same time you need to add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) to your test plan.

1. Increase "Number of Threads" to `100` on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level
2. Add [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of the SOAP/XML-RPC Request
3. Set "Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by" to `100`
4. Make sure that [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) has following configuration:

   - "Recycle on EOF?" - `true`
   - "Stop thread on EOF?" - `false`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the quick answer. With the synchronizing timer had to modify "Sharing mode" option to "Current Thread Group" in http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config.